# Can't get SipDemo to register

Tags: android, sip

I am developing an application that will make SIP calls using the SIP APIs. I want to use the SipDemo code as my starting point, but when I run SipDemo on my devices (Nexus or Galaxy Tab) I always get "Registration failed. Please check settings." I am using the same username/password/server information that works successfully in Sipdroid.

I inserted log messages in setRegistrationListener to follow what's happening, and I will see onRegistrationDone fire, but then it seems to register again, because it will then see  Registration failed with the error message "registration timed out" followed by registration failed with the error message "cannot initiate a new transaction to execute".

I've been beating my head about this for a few days, and I've got a deadline rapidly approaching. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, or if you could point me to some other examples/tutorials of how to use the SIP APIs.

Comment: Are you using the default source code which was provided by the SipDemo or have you changed something?

Comment: I am just using the default source code. I was hoping for a solid starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it! The demo wants to use UDP by default, but I was able to make it connect by hardcoding the protocol to TCP. I have a netgear modem from charter cable, and I have seen several reports of it blocking access. I assume the two are related, but for now I'm just happy to have it work so I can continue my development.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey sanddune I have same problem. I've been tried for many days, and I m always getting error "Registration failed ..." When I m using jitsi or sipdroid its okey, but not work on sipdemo. I cant connect. Actually I dont understand your fixed method. Can you explain? thank you.

Comment: Can please put a picture or code snippet where did you changed your code to get it work for you..

Comment: Hi, how did you change the SIPdemo to use TCP instead of UDP? I also followed the SipDemo but cannot get it register, it failed with the cannot initiate a new transaction to execute com.android.server.sip.sipsessiongroup

Comment: SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,
                        domain);
                builder.setPassword(password);
                //builder.setDisplayName(username);
                builder.setAuthUserName(username);
                builder.setPort(5060);
                builder.setProtocol("TCP");
                builder.setOutboundProxy("proxy.sipthor.net");
                SipProfile mSipProfile = builder.build();

Answer (score 0):

Check the logcat, it should have more information about what failed. Also if you have control over the server, check the server logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not alone http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/detail?id=60.
I would suggest that you try what people tried there: i.e.

- Try another router.
- Change port in code. Read the link for more details.