# Sip Demo Android cant't register on phone

Tags: android, sip

how to change protocol ot TCP in Sipdemo?
I am refering to this.Me too facing same problem.
[Can't get SipDemo to register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455088/cant-get-sipdemo-to-register)

Answer (score 1):

Type this into your code before the `builder.setProtocol("TCP");` to change the protocol.. So the snippet of the code would look like this.

```
public void connect(String username,String password,String server)
{
    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, server);

        builder.setPassword(password);
        builder.setProtocol("TCP");
        mSipProfile = builder.build();
       }
}
```